# What does l6fzcv stand for in DynamoDB DAX cluster endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

When reading DynamoDB DAX documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.concepts.cluster.html

I noticed random alphanumeric character being used in the cluster endpoint. These are normally l6fzcv etc. Does anyone know what they stand for? Is it constant for DAX clusters in a region?
Example endpoint from docs: dax://my-cluster.l6fzcv.dax-clusters.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe the random alphanumeric characters you are seeing in the cluster endpoint, such as "l6fzcv" in "my-cluster.l6fzcv.dax-clusters.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", are not a constant for DAX clusters in a region, nor do they have any specific meaning. They are simply unique identifiers that are generated by AWS to identify the specific DAX cluster. I believe the typical endpoint format for DAX cluster is: clustername.dax.region.amazonaws.com